# Next.js: Calling import from different endpoint executes the code again

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

Here's the simplified example I made for this question.

Let's say I want to keep a state on the server side.

**components/dummy.ts**

```js
console.log('init array')
let num: number = 0
const increment: () => number = () => num++
export { increment }
```

Also I have two end-points, p1 and p2 that I want to share that state.

**pages/api/x/p1.ts**

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { increment } from '../../../components/dummy'

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<number>
) {
  res.status(200).json(increment())
}
```

**pages/api/x/p2.ts**

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { increment } from '../../../components/dummy'

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<number>
) {
  res.status(200).json(increment())
}
```

These are are the two APIs, and then I have some pages fetching the same using *getServerSideProps*

**pages/x/p3.tsx**

```js
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next'
import React from 'react'
import { increment } from '../../components/dummy'

interface CompProps {
  num: number
}

const Comp: React.FC<CompProps> = ({ num }) => <>{num}</>

export default Comp

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({}) => ({
  props: {
    num: increment(),
  },
})
```

**pages/x/p4.tsx**

```js
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next'
import React from 'react'
import { increment } from '../../components/dummy'

interface CompProps {
  num: number
}

const Comp: React.FC<CompProps> = ({ num }) => <>{num}</>

export default Comp

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({}) => ({
  props: {
    num: increment(),
  },
})
```

So basically 2 issues.

**On Dev (yarn dev)**
Now when I hit api/x/p1 I get a 0 then 1, 2, 3.
But now when I hit api/x/p2 I get a 0, and now p1 is also reset to this new value, from this point on, p1 and p2 are sharing the same state. I can alternate between p1 and p2 and get a constant increment.

What I want to understand here is the nature of import.
How can I avoid the code to run again with each import coming from a new end-point.

**On Prod (yarn build && yarn start)**
On prod it's better because api/x/p1 and api/x/p2 share the same state.

But by using **GetServerSideProps** api/p3 and api/p4 share the same state between themselves. But that is a different one shared by p1 and p2.

So basically using the **/api** routes and **GetServerSideProps** have their own state that's not being shared.

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `const increment: () => number = () => num++`?  Why isn't it just `const increment = () => num++`?

Comment: It depends on your environment, for default the imported modules are cached/shared, but  something is resetting them, please share more details about all your env/architecture/tools/transpilers/etc

Comment: @jfriend00 I just like to have the type-declaration in front to ensure the return type and the types of parameters. This is a simple case so it would work fine without it as well, but you can say it's a habit.

Comment: @jone-polvora It's the default NextJS project with TS. Created using yarn create next-app --typescript. Any specific files you want me to share? As I'm not an expert on Node back-ends.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce you issue.
I've created a sample project in order to check the module behavior, and have confirmed that the modules are imported only once, cached, keeping state.
Check it out:

```js
/* index.js */
import './mod1.js'
import './mod2.js'
```

```js
/* mod1.js */
import { increment } from "./shared.js";

setInterval(() => {
    increment()
}, 2000);
```

```js
/* mod2.js */
import { increment } from "./shared.js";

setInterval(() => {
    increment()
}, 2000);
```

```js
/* shared.js */ 
let num = 0
const increment = () => {
    num++
    console.log(num)
}

export { increment }
```

```js
node index.js

outputs:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
^C
```

My guess: When you're running the app in development mode, NextJs compiles modules on demand, when it's needed. So, when you go to the first route, you can see in stdout (vscode console) nextjs printing logs compiling files. When it finishes, there's a feature in development mode called hot-reload which will load automagically the new compiled module into memory. Then, when you go to the second route, the other module starts compiling, and when is ready, Next Js will hot reload this new fresh module into memory. This sometimes may cause the state of the app to be reset (unload modules then reload it again). I guess this is whats happening. To confirm, you can try run the builded app (next build command). Then there will be no hot reload when running the compiled/bundle application, so no state will be changed.

Comment: Thank you for this, yes I was running in dev. Now I have added more details while running on prod. The issue is between /api and GetServerSideProps.

Comment: After reading your update, I know now that i'm right. The reset of state between api1 and 2 is because of compilation process. After both modules are built and loaded, there's no reset state issue anymore. The 3 and 4 apis that uses getServerSideProps() have another state is because these pieces of code are running on server side, not client side, so they have its own states (server & client)

Comment: Yes you're right it was because of the compliation process. Thanks. But both the /api routes and getServerSideProps() are on the server side. I think it's not a NodeJS issue, but it's specific to NextJS.

Comment: my bad, I forgot the /api folder is server side.

Comment: I think there is some scoping in the way nextjs/react handle importing modules. Anyway, the default behavior of importing modules is what I could prove with the code of my answer, with pure node/javascript without any framework doing transpilation/compilation/etc. With nextjs and other frameworks, there are caveats. The recommendation is to not trust in this kind of state management. For this purpose, there are many libraries that do this job very consistently. I recommend react-redux with redux-toolkit to manage local state.